# Changes to a Dynamic list do not result in refresh and rendering of my UI

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

I am adding new nodes / members to a BindableCollection list called People, but I do not see the result in my UI

I am using Caliburn.Micro, and MongoDB in a WPF project to learn how it works. When I add a new person to my list, I see in the DB table but my form does not update automatically. I have seen some refrences online about DataGrid control may not be a good choice for real time dynamic rendering, and I am reading everything I can find on the topic, but have not figured out what I am doing wrong.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="People" AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue"
              CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FullName"  Binding="{Binding Path=FullName}" />
            <!--<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="FullName" Binding ="{Binding Path=FullName}"/>-->
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is Alive" Binding="{Binding Path=IsAlive}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Primary Address">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PrimaryAddress.FullAddress}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Addresses}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=PrimaryAddress}">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FullAddress}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>

                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateOfBirth, StringFormat=d}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DateOfBirth}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I like to see the changes to People list in real time. My ShellView.xaml.cs has:

```
public partial class ShellView : Window
{
    MongoCRUD da = new MongoCRUD("mongoChallenge");
    PersonModel newPerson = new PersonModel();

    public ShellView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();   
    }

    private void NewPerson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        newPerson.FirstName = firstName.Text;
        newPerson.LastName = lastName.Text;
        //List<PersonModel> People = new List<PersonModel>();
        AddressModel newAddress = new AddressModel();
        newAddress.StreetAddress = StreetAddress.Text;
        newAddress.City = City.Text;
        newAddress.State = State.Text;
        newAddress.ZipCode = ZipCode.Text;
        newPerson.PrimaryAddress = newAddress;
        da.InsertRecord<PersonModel>("challengeUsers", newPerson);
        List<PersonModel> updatedList = new List<PersonModel>();
        updatedList = da.LoadRecords<PersonModel>("challengeUsers");      
    }

    private void Clear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        firstName.Text = "";
        lastName.Text = "";
        StreetAddress.Text = "";
        City.Text = "";
        State.Text = "";
        ZipCode.Text = "";
        DateOfBirth.SelectedDate = new DateTime();

        //dateOfBirth.DisplayDate = DateTime.Today;
        //dateOfBirth.ClearValue(); Not sure how to reset the date of birth when I clear the form
    }

    private void DateOfBirth_SelectedDateChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        newPerson.DateOfBirth = (DateTime)DateOfBirth.SelectedDate;

    }
}
```

And my ShellViewModel.cs has:

```
public class ShellViewModel: Screen
{

    MongoCRUD da = new MongoCRUD("mongoChallenge");
    BindableCollection<PersonModel> testList = new BindableCollection<PersonModel>();
    private BindableCollection<PersonModel> _people;
    private AddressModel _primaryAddress;
    private PersonModel _newPerson;

    public PersonModel NewPerson
    {
        get { return _newPerson; }
        set
        {
            _newPerson = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => NewPerson);
        }
    }
    public void Update (List<PersonModel> list)
    {
        //People = list;
        People.AddRange(list);
    }
    public BindableCollection<PersonModel> People
    {
        get
        {
            //load records from MongoDB table called challengeUsers
            List<PersonModel> temp = da.LoadRecords<PersonModel>("challengeUsers");
            _people = new BindableCollection<PersonModel>(temp);
            return _people;
        }
        set
        {

            //load records from MongoDB table called challengeUsers
            List<PersonModel> temp = da.LoadRecords<PersonModel>("challengeUsers");
            _people = new BindableCollection<PersonModel>(temp);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => People);
        }
    }
    private DateTime _dateOfBirth;

    public DateTime DateOfBirth
    {
        get { return _dateOfBirth; }
        set
        {
            _dateOfBirth = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange<DateTime>(() => DateOfBirth);
        }
    }
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        MongoCRUD da = new MongoCRUD("mongoChallenge");
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => NewPerson);
        List<PersonModel> temp = da.LoadRecords<PersonModel>("challengeUsers");
        People = new BindableCollection<PersonModel>(temp);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => People);
    }
    private String _fullName;

    public String FullName
    {
        get { return _fullName; }
        set
        {
            _fullName = value;
            //FullName changed
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => FullName);
        }
    }


    public AddressModel PrimaryAddress
    {
        get { return _primaryAddress; }
        set
        {
            //Primary Address changed
            _primaryAddress = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PrimaryAddress);
        }
    }

}
```

Thank you so much.

Update on 5/21/19 - Here is what I see when I try to change People collection: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9wje.png)

Comment: Any chance you could post the code that contains the Collection you re binding to?  (CodeBehind/ViewModel)

Comment: Hi yes; I just updated it.

Comment: Where do you create an instance of your viewmodel and assign it to the window’s DataContext?

Comment: It's a bad idea to do processing in your getter. Process in setters. Just return the results in getters.  Rather than just adding a new record to People you seem to possibly be intending rebuilding your entire collection every time there's a change. Which parts of your code do we look at to understand what happens when you're adding a new record?

Comment: @Andy that is what I seem to have trouble with; thank you for focusing on it. As you see I used NewPerson_Click to create a Person model, but People is not a collection in ShellView. It seems to be a UI field, and I do not see options like Add(list member) using itellisense. I recognized I have to add to the list; I could not do it. That is why I re-queried the db. This is btw what Ed mentioned too; you both see what I am missing.  Aside from the code I have shared I have a couple of other classes that just define the objects and db methods. That is all.

Comment: Your processing should all be in the viewmodel. Or at least initiated from there and acting on objects encapsulate complicated things or access other layers.  Yiu should be using an icommand rather than click handler. A bit like https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx  If yiu do that then you have a reference to people where you're do something with a person. You can add to people and call into your model layer to persist change to your database. Rather than textbox.text, bind text to a property in your viewmodel and work with that.

Comment: Ok got it. I'll read the content. Thank you.